# Run integration tests with Maven Failsafe with fresh program state

Tags: java, maven, integration-testing

I am finding that my tests are failing on my Jenkins server due to the program state being reused (as opposed to running each entry point in its own state). So in other words, **one test has a side effect that causes another to fail**.

Two of my tests modify some static variable. One depends on it being the default. The fact that the other test changes the variable causes the test to fail. The manner of the tests are never meant to be run in the same program state (these test the program from entry point to exit).

How can I make Maven run each test standalone?

**Possibly relevant information:**

- Maven version 3.2.2
- Failsafe version 2.6
- Failsafe has execution goals are `integration-test` and `verify`
- Tests are just JUnit 4.11 tests
- Behavior confirmed on both Linux and OS X
- Using Java 1.8.0_05
- Modules aren't being used. We're running the integration tests with `clean integration-test` (I realize now that it should have been `clean verify`, but that doesn't matter for this issue)
- I guess they're really more like system tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [fork new vm](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html) which is, per your question *How can I make Maven run each test standalone?*, what you want.

In integration-test, it is the failsafe plugin, and there exists the same parameter ([forkCount](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html), etc), so I guess you can fork the VM.

[edit] since forkCount default to 1, it is the [reuseForks](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#reuseForks) parameter you should set to false.

Comment: Great, this worked! A side note that I had to change the version of failsafe to 2.17, too.

Comment: Yeah it was a little bit strange cause your are using many up-to-date things but maven-failsafe-plugin was old ;-)

Comment: On a side note, you can use `mvn versions:display-dependency-updates` to check for newest dependencies, and `mvn versions:display-plugin-updates` for plugin update.